# onClick of list Item blocking onItemClick in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have created custom list view which have one button, My problem is after adding button in list item onItemClick of list view has stop working. Is there any way to keep both listeners working?

Comment: show me your ListItem layout

Comment: Please read this before asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Simple Plan my list item xml has so meny things so I cant put it into comment, but in short it contains images textviews and one button. before adding button onItamClick was working

Comment: @VarunKarhadkar i faced the same issue in past and i solved it just by my asnwer given below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set this to your `ListItem root Layout`

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and set

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to your `Buttons`. It's seems working in my case.